# Snapping edges to surface not working in blender 2.8

Tags: modeling, workflow, snapping

I'm trying to snap the bottom extruded edges to the helper mesh but it doesn't work. How can you do that in blender 2.8?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view orientation matters when snapping.

Use this snapping settings:

[image]

And to snap in your case, use side view <kbd>Numpad</kbd><kbd>3</kbd>, then with edges selected grab (without moving) and validate:

[image]

Can also use <kbd>G</kbd> then <kbd>X</kbd> (constrained the projection) to snap with same orientation in this case.

Comment: Thanks! The action key in 2.8 is middle mouse button.

Comment: Very strange! If you don't look at the surface Numpad 3 it doesn't work; blender sometimes feels like a coin flip, a competitive one.

Comment: Or you can force the axis, as said at the end of the answer...

Answer (score 2):

Some variation on this?

- Set  the origin of your object is at its base..
- In Edit mode, assign the extruded vertices to a Vertex Group
- In Object Mode, Switch on Snap, to Face, Align Rotation
- Give the object a *Shrinkwrap* modifier, aimed at the Vertex Group, targeted on the surface.

Then, you can slide an object around on a surface, keeping contact.

[image]

In this case, the disc is up in Z, so I set the *Shrinkwrap* to negative Z projection. This may seem long-winded, but this can be a useful modelling routine.

You can take this further, making a flange, matching normals, etc., to make a Decal, but that's more than you want.

Comment: Isn't there a shorter way such as https://youtu.be/TAlzJC2uzIU?t=1023 . In that case the vertexes were snapped to the closest surface (in this case the helper mesh).

Comment: True.I would use that, if the edge was on its own, but when it's attached to the rest of the object, I find it really hard to control, and stay in the right relation to the rest. Is that just me? Have you found a way?

Comment: Not yet. Would it be possible to create a separate object from the extruded edge (it won't be used anyway (only the projection of edges on the surface counts)).

Comment: Yes . You could create a Custom Orientation from an appropriate normal, E, drop, G Z, (along the normal) to make your part _from_ the snapped edge.